# Gitlab Atom feed entries link configuration

Tags: rss, gitlab, atom-feed

I just find out my Gitlab's Atom feed does not serve public URL for entries links.

My Atom feed URL is at http://MY_PUBLIC_URL.ltd/dashboard.atom?private_token=XXXXXXXX

By generated entries are like:

```xml
<entry>
    <id>tag:192.168.0.105,2014-06-03:189</id>
    <link href="http://192.168.0.105/team/project/issues/2"/>
    <title>User commented on issue #16 at My project / my repo</title>
    <updated>2014-06-03T05:46:26Z</updated>
    <media:thumbnail width="40" height="40" url="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7fe0e43839bea9ad3e28344e6f9306bb?s=40&amp;d=mm"/>
    <author>
      <name>Author's name</name>
      <email>user@bMY_PUBLIC_DOMAIN.ltd</email>
    </author>
    <summary type="xhtml">
    </summary>
  </entry>
```

So as you can see, it uses 192.168.0.105 instead of MY_PUBLIC_URL, even though gitlab.yml is defined so:

```yaml
production: &base
  gitlab:
    host: MY_PUBLIC_URL
    port: 80
```

Comment: thats no longer the case - in latest gitlab version 8.x, maybe therefore close/delete this question?